# Does the following transformation preserve context-freeness?

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I encountered this problem involving manipulating a context-free language. Let $L$ be a context-free language. Define $L^{\#} = \{ x : x^i \in L$ for every $i=0,1,2,...\}$. Is $L^{\#}$ always context-free?
My guess is that it will preserve context-freeness. Can anyone provide an elementary proof of this?

Comment: Perhaps for http://cs.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I did not know there is one. Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean "for every $i$" or maybe "for some $i$"? For example $i = 0$ implies that $L^\#$ is empty unless $L$ contains the empty word.

Comment: [Cross-posted](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10183/does-the-following-transformation-preserve-context-freeness) to CS.  The answer there looks good.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\Sigma$ = {$a,b,c$} and $L=${$a^nb^nc(a^*b^*c)^*:n\geq0$}.

Now, L is clearly context-free since its a concatenation between a context free language and a regular language.

However, $L$#={$(a^nb^nc(a^*b^*c)^*)^k:n\geq0,k\geq0$}, which can be shown, using the pumping lemma, not to be context free.

So, the claim is false.

I hope my reasoning is correct.

Comment: Um, I was really tired last night and thinking nonsense.  Sorry!  Incorrect comment deleted.
By the way, the word is 'concatenation'.

Comment: However, your $L^\sharp$ is not correct, for example $a^2 b^2 c abc$ is in $L^\sharp$.  (I made a similar mistake in my attempt at an answer, now deleted.)

Comment: Ah, yes, I see the mistake there... fixed it up a bit, i think it's right now. Can you find any fault with it?

Comment: Well, isn't $\{(a^n b^n c (a^* b^* c)^*)^k : n,k\geq 0\}$ the same language as $L$ (and therefore context-free)?